# Функция mail() на сервере.

Tags: email, php

Я пытаюсь добавить к регистрации проверку `e-mail` адреса. Добавил, но проверить работает ли не могу. Сообщения на почту не приходят. Я прочитал на форумах, что нужно включить функцию `mail()` на своем сервере. Как это сделать не знаю. Помогите. Устанавливал  локальный сервер `Apache`.

Comment: Вы про утилиту sendmail говорите?

Comment: Если у вас linux подобная ос:<br>
sudo apt-get install sendmail

Comment: Да sendmail. Я уже скрипт написал, но а что сделать дальше ОС vista?

Comment: народ, хорош тупить!!! (поставьте... чего-то... и т.д. и т.п.)
на http://apache.org есть пакеты дин. модулей для apache под любую ось. и SMTP и POP и остальные! там же есть и все доки, правда на англ. ставите и настраиваете. настройки апача прописаны в файле httpd.conf, файл текстовый. любые модули и другой софт есть на русскояз. ресурсе denwer.ru там же есть и доки и видео!!! очень рекомендую! а Vistu лучше снести и заменить на никсы!!! (без SMTP кстати можно, но ооочень очень сложно! ;-))

Answer (score 5):

Поставьте себе любой SMTP сервер на комп. Настройте чтобы он пересылал письма через любую вашу почту. В настройках PHP поставьте его ип и порт, на который настроете и остальное, что надо и все. При обращении скрипт будет смотреть в настройках, куда обращаться и спокойно отсылать письма посредством вашего смтп сервера.
P.S. что надо искать-

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
```

Вот тут и меняете порт, если настроите не на 25-й или ИП, если сервер на другой машине, в сети.
P.P.S. Я, например, в свое время просто настраивал на СМТП сервер провайдера. У него всегда есть для своих абонентов такой сервер беспарольный, но с границей отправки 100 писем в день  и 10 в час. Но для моих нужд хватало, ибо тоже делал просто проверку мыл и отсылку уведомлений.

Comment: А можно какнить без SMTP?))))

Comment: А как без него, если только он может отправлять письма? Я вам написал дополнение. Если есть у провайдера свободный смтп, то на него настройтесь. Или просто поищите в инете, если найдете. Помните только, что настройка в пхп указывает только на ип или имя хоста и порт. Больше ничего для винды.

Answer (score 2):

OS у вас какая? Vista.

Могу посоветовать не использовать mail(), возьмите класс PHPMailer, настройте его на сервак yandex.ru по SMTP. В примерах к классу довольно толково описано, как настраивать этот класс.

Comment: Vista )))

Comment: <small><b>оффтоп</b><br>
Для вашего же добра начните с переустановки ОС, хотябы на XP или 7, Vista это же ужас, не?</small>

Comment: Я знаю, что ужас, но тут столько всего, пока не закончу с сайтом перестанавливать не хочется))) Придется целую неделю все восстанавливать)

Comment: @LordySL, висту можно обновить до windows 7 без потери и переустановки каких-либо пользовательских программ и файлов.

PS Не посмотрел на дату комментария.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что проще было бы залить скрипт на какой-нибудь хостинг и там уже проверить. Если что, то могу помочь с хостингом и выделить папку на фтп-шнике.

Answer (score 1):

В коде тестируй просто по условию !mail(), потом выкладывай на сервер и проверяй доходят ли  письма.